# How to create a type for an object whose elements have values that are related?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am receiving some arbitrary table data, from which I will create a sortable table in React:

```json
{
    columns: ["key1", "key2"],
    rows: [
        { key1: "value 1,1", key2: "value 2,1" },
        { key1: "value 1,2", key2: "value 2,2" },
    ],
}
```

I do not know what the table will contain, so `'key1' | 'key2' ...` are unknown to my code. However, I do know that the keys of `rows[i]` will all be elements of `columns`. Is there a way to enforce this in the types of the two objects? What if I have both as arguments to a function? I tried something like this:

```js
type TableProps<Row> = {
    cols: (keyof Row)[];
    rows: Row[];
}
const Table: React.FC<TableProps<Record<string, any>> = ({ cols, rows }) => { ... }
```

However, this seems equivalent to defining `TableProps` simply as

```js
type TableProps = {
    cols: string[];
    rows: Record<string, any>[];
}
```

which is not a strong enough statement. It would be nice if I could type the column-names as a string-literal without fixed values, and the rows as `Record`s with those (unknown) string literals as keys. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Also, it would be nice to express somehow that `cols` is not just any old selection of the values of the string-literal in question, but *all* of them in some order, once each. But maybe that is too much to ask.

I'm not sure it will even add much benefit to make such firm restrictions through typing, but in my head it sounds so simple to express what I want, so it bothers me that I can't figure out how to do it.

Edit:

To rephrase my question:

How can I type the following function, so that I get an error from typescript in the appropriate place?

```js
const example = (tableData: ???): void => {
    const {cols, rows} = tableData;
    
    if (cols.length === 0 || rows.length === 0) { return; }
    
    const ex1 = rows[0][cols[0]]; // OK
    const badKey = 'some random string'
    const ex2 = rows[0][badKey];  // ERROR
    // badKey here may in fact actually be one of the keys of rows[0]
    // at runtime. TypeScript cannot know that, but that is okay.
}
```

Edit II:
Changed the title from

> Can you create a string-literal type without knowing the string values beforehand?

to

> How to create a type for an object whose elements have values that are related?

Comment: Unless I've terribly misread the question, you're asking for compile-time checks on runtime values. I don't see how that can work.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLyx4W) ?If keys have some pattern, I mean `string-number`, I can make type and value more precise.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I don't want to actually check runtime values. All I want is to let TypeScript enforce that only the elements of `cols` are valid keys of each `rows[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to the above, but in truth I am not satisfied yet.

```js
const example = <T extends string>(
    tableData: { cols: T[], rows: Record<T, any>[] }
): void => {    
    const {cols, rows} = tableData;
    if (cols.length === 0 || rows.length === 0) { return; }
    
    const ex1 = rows[0][cols[0]]; // OK
    const ex2 = rows[0]['asdf'];  // ERROR: 
    // Property 'asdf' does not exist on type 'Record<T, any>'.
}
```

I worry that this approach would make the function tricky to use, since I would have to have this generic `T` everywhere as context whenever dealing with a `tableData` as function argument or value. It would be nice if I could just define some loose type somewhere, which encodes this flexibility that the generic `T` gives in this case, and use that in all places where a `TableData` pops up. I will keep trying to find a solution to the overall problem.

Apologies for any confusion, as I realise the title of the question is starting to lose relevance. I will continue to read up to see if I can get a more general solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible, for the simple reason that the typing is not related to when your application runs. Also, the JS is not typed, only the TS is.

This means that you can't enforce typings for when you have data in the application, you can only enforce typings for when you code.

The simplest typing I would think of in this case is this one :

```
interface DatasetRow {
  [key: string]: string;
}
type Dataset = DatasetRow[];
```

It's very simple but that's what represents your data the best.

But to better answer you, maybe you should tell us (me?) what are you trying to achieve in the first place ?

Comment: I don't want to check runtime values. I only want TypeScript to complain if, for instance, I try to access values from an object using any old string. Only the elements of `cols` are known to be keys of `rows[i]` for sure.

I don't think this is so different from how if, say, I make a string literal
```
```

Comment: I don't think this is so different from how if, say, I make a string literal, and define a record to have it as its keys. Then, anything typed as being one of the values in that string literal will be a valid key to TypeScript, even if the actual value at runtime is wrong. The only difference is, not even the code knows the values of the string literal in this case.

Comment: Well if you want to enforce that rule, you need to have the values at runtime ... See the issue there ? If you do not know the values of the column when you are coding, then you cannot enforce the type. And when you have the values at runtime, it's too late for that.

Comment: The only way for you to achieve what you want is to know the values at runtime. Otherwise, you will need some custom JS logic, **NOT** typings, to do that.

Comment: I don't want to enforce values though. I just want to restrict what is permitted in the code. The actual values of the objects that I receive as input can be totally wrong, but I must assume that they have a certain shape. And my assumptions are pretty strong, since I assume that the keys of all the objects in `rows` are the same, and that they are listed in a specific order in `cols`.

Comment: Yeah but that's the issue, objects that you **RECEIVE** are received at runtime ...

Comment: Disagree. The whole point of types is to check *static* runtime values. Of course, you can't check dynamic runtime values, but in this case, it's static. See OP's answer.

Comment: @caTS you don't use types at runtime for the simple reason that they don't exist. So using types to check anything at runtime is simply not possible. Types are used before transpilation.

Comment: What I mean is, you can use types to check *static* values, because they exist at compile time, just like OP's problem. They have some static values, and want to check if they are correct before running the code.

Comment: @caTS Maybe that's what I am failing to see here. I will stop there because the discussion is going nowhere, my final take being that I didn't correctly understood the issue !